# Android Virtual Device Screen Shot(No WiFi)

Tags: android, wifi, screenshot, android-virtual-device

I have developed an application which connects to devices on LAN and through Internet connection.  It is complete and ready to be released.  Previously I would just run the app on an AVD and take screen shots that way.  I've got a problem here though.  My app requires WiFi connection to devices in order to function but since the AVD does not support this I cant get screen shots this way.  Any ideas?  I havnt seen a really good screen capture app for Android, if you know of one please let me know.

THanks

Comment: you havenn't searched enough

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.  Android solved this in Android 4.0 and later.  Just hold power button and volume down button and it will take a screen shot.  Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

While on-device screenshot has only recently been supported, you have since the very early versions of the SDK been able to take screenshots of an Android device through the DDMS tool of the SDK when the device is connected to a computer via ADB.